# Supersized Plugin [jQuery] to show specific set of images if a variable is 'true'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, supersized

I have used the Supersized Fullscreen Gallery plugin for my website. I'm having trouble approaching a function I want it to perform and I can't seem to get any hints anywhere.

The gallery is constantly on in the background, but I want to make it so that when you are on a specific area of the site (in other words, if a variable is 'true') the normal set of images is put aside and a new set of images starts slideshowing, and then when you return (when the variable is 'false') it slideshows the normal set of images again. I don't want one set of images to be accessible while the others are playing.

Comment: Please show an example in jsfiddle or in your own test site for us to better undertand the problem.

Comment: Basically I just need to be able to have 2 versions of these plugins available I guess, and depending on a simple "true" or "false" statement it switches between the 2? There wouldn't really be anything that I can show here other than the Supersized script itself which can be found here: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is to create a function that gets the "true" or "false" boolean with the different type of sets of images set for both before loading it into the slides:[//images] that is provided by the plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, though I'm not sure specifically how to do this.